# Why in list comprehensions is if-else before while just if is after?

Tags: python, list-comprehension

A general question about python iterable comprehensions:

Why is it that for a statement like this

```
[s for s in x if s>2]
```

The `if` goes after the `for`, but for a statement like

```
[s if s>2 else None for s in x]
```

The `if... else` goes before the `for`?

Comment: That's just how the syntax is defined! https://docs.python.org/3/tutorial/datastructures.html#list-comprehensions, here is the grammar for it: https://docs.python.org/3/reference/grammar.html

Comment: Only guido van Rossum can answer this question, and I doubt he's inclined to.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

The only thing the conditional expression and the comprehension filter have in common is the shared use of the *keyword* `if`.

`a if b else c` is a conditional expression. It's purpose is to guarantee a value whether or not `b` is true. Its use is not specific to a list comprehension; in `[s if s > 2 else None for s in x]` it simply serves as the expression used to provide a value for the new list, given a value `s` from `x`.

The other use of `if` is part of the syntax of the list comprehension itself. It's not part of an expression; it specifies a *filter* which is used to determine if a particular value from the iterable should even be passed to the expression.

If you think of a list comprehension as a combination of `map` and `filter`, then the expression takes the place of the function argument to `map`, while the `if` filter takes the place of a call to `filter`. That is, you can rewrite any general list comprehension

```
[ <expression> for s in xs if <p>]
```

as a combination of `map` and `filter` thus:

```
list(map(lambda s: <expression>, filter(lambda s: <p>, xs)))
```

You can see [PEP-202](https://www.python.org/dev/peps/pep-0202/) for a discussion about list comprehensions (though it is older and doesn't document any other syntax that may have been considered), and [PEP-308](https://www.python.org/dev/peps/pep-0308/) for conditional expressions which *does* discuss some alternative syntax considered.

Answer (score 2):

`if-else` is not restricted to list comprehensions and can be used in assignment statements and so forth. It has no special meaning inside the list comprehension.

The `if` syntax after the `for` expression selects which elements are included in the comprehension, which the `if-else` cannot do, and so its use is specific to comprehensions.

Answer (score 0):

In the first case, the `if` is part of the expression for what each element of the created list is; in the second, it is deciding whether or not to include an element (and hence has no need for an `else`).

Answer (score 0):

The most general form of list comprehension is this:
`[expression1_of_x for x in iterable if expression2_of_x]`  where  `expressio2_of_x` is optional.
So all the following list comprehension is accepted:(`expression1_of_x`,`expressio2_of_x`)
1. `[s for s in x if s>2]` is okay. ( s, s>2)
2. `[s if s>2 else None for s in x]` (s if s>2 else None, nil )
3. `[s if s>2 else None for s in x if s > 10]` (s if s>2 else None,s>10)
For more information see [the docs](https://docs.python.org/3/tutorial/datastructures.html#list-comprehensions).